# PHP: Help troubleshooting when echo's won't execute?

Tags: php, echo, php4

I asked this question here originally:

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/439484/why-arent-more-echos-being-executed

uploaded to the server(form):

http://cs4.sunyocc.edu/~j.d.dancks/onestopshop/index.php

sort_mysql results sorts arrays of other queries and returns a 2d arrays of data that was found in all of the data arrays.

EDIT: I solved the problem with echos, now I have a problem with this function (I think):

```
function sort_mysql_results()
{
    echo "<p>begin smr</p>";
    $match=array();
    $c_match=0;
    $num_it = 0;
    $num_args = func_num_args();
    $c = 0;
    $args = func_get_args();
    while(isset($args[0][$num_it]))
    {
        echo "<p>sort mysql beginning of loop</p>";
        $skip=false;
        $name = $args[0][$num_it]['item_name'];
        $i=1;
        while(isset($args[$i])&&!$skip)
        {
            $skip = !check($args[$i],$name);
            $i++;
        }
        $num_it++;
        if(!$skip)
        {
            $match[$c_match] = $args[0];
            $c_match++;
        }
    }
    echo "<p>Num args: ".$num_args.", Iterations: ".$num_it."</p>";
    return $match;
}
```

The function gets called like this:

```
$match = sort_mysql_results(sort_soundex_results($queries[0]),get_array($queries[1]));
```

Now $match is supposed to be an array. For some reason its not. I try to print results into a table like so:

```
if(count($match)>0)
{
    $num=0;
    echo "<table>\n
    <tr>\n
    <td>Name</td><td>Category</td><td>Description</td>\n
    </tr>\n";
    while(isset($match[$num]))
    {
        echo "<tr>\n
        <a href=\"product2.php?id=".$match[$num]['ItemID']."\"><td>".$match[$num]['item_name']."</td><td>".$match[$num]['cat_name']."</td><td>".$match[$num]['descr']."</td></a>\n
        </tr>\n";
        $num++;
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}
else
{
    echo "<p>No matches found. Go back and try different search criteria</p>\n";
}
```

for reference the mysql table being queried looks like:

```
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
 | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
 | item_name   | varchar(100) | NO   |     |                     |                | 
 | ItemID      | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
 | cat_name    | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |                | 
 | userID      | mediumint(9) | NO   |     |                     |                | 
 | descr       | text         | NO   |     |                     |                | 
 | image       | tinytext     | YES  |     | NULL                |                | 
 | date        | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                | 
 | highest_bid | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | 0.00                |                | 
 | time_expire | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                | 
 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

EDIT: Hope you,re still with me. I did some further debugging:

```
...
if(count($match)>0)
{
    echo "<p>space</p><h2>In IF STATEMENT VALUE OF MATCH BEFORE WHILE LOOP</h2><p>space</p>\n";
    echo "<p>space</p><p>space</p><p>space</p>\n";
    var_dump($match);
    echo "<p>space</p><p>space</p><p>space</p>\n";
    echo "<h2>VALUE OF match[num]</h2>\n";
    echo "<p>space</p><p>space</p><p>space</p>\n";
    var_dump($match[0]);
    echo "<p>space</p><p>space</p><p>space</p>\n";
...
```

check this out:

```
 In IF STATEMENT VALUE OF MATCH BEFORE WHILE LOOP

 space

 space

 space

space

array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["item_name"]=> string(10) "Squat Rack" ["ItemID"]=> string(1) "8" ["cat_name"]=> string(16) "Sports Equipment" ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" ["descr"]=> string(25) "Comes with 275 lbs plates" ["image"]=> string(14) "squat_rack.jpg" ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-15 09:34:36" ["highest_bid"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["time_expire"]=> string(19) "2012-12-01 00:00:01" ["src"]=> string(4) "S362" ["src2"]=> string(4) "S362" ["result"]=> string(1) "1" } } }
 space

 space

 space

 VALUE OF match[num]

 space

 space

 space

 array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["item_name"]=> string(10) "Squat Rack" ["ItemID"]=> string(1) "8" ["cat_name"]=> string(16) "Sports Equipment" ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" ["descr"]=> string(25) "Comes with 275 lbs plates" ["image"]=> string(14) "squat_rack.jpg" ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-15 09:34:36" ["highest_bid"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["time_expire"]=> string(19) "2012-12-01 00:00:01" ["src"]=> string(4) "S362" ["src2"]=> string(4) "S362" ["result"]=> string(1) "1" } }
 space

 space

 space
```

Looks like its supposed to. Whats going on here???

Comment: can someone tell me how to improve the question?

Comment: PHP4 is **ancient**, please upgrade at once.

Comment: not an option. Im on the school server

Comment: Give your "system administrator" a slap for me, will you?

Comment: I sure will. OK I know what the problem is. $match is a 3D array, so when I dereference to $match[num] I still have a 2D array.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified sort_mysql_results:

```
function sort_mysql_results()
{
    echo "<p>begin smr</p>";
    $match=array();
    $c_match=0;
    $num_it = 0;
    $c = 0;
    $args = func_get_args();
    while(isset($args[0][$num_it]))
    {
        echo "<p>sort mysql beginning of loop</p>";
        $skip=false;
        $name = $args[0][$num_it]['item_name'];
        $i=1;
        while(isset($args[$i])&&!$skip)
        {
            $skip = !check($args[$i],$name);
            $i++;
        }
        if(!$skip) //if found in another parameter
        {
            $match[$c_match] = $args[0][$num_it];
            $c_match++;
        }
        $num_it++;
    }
    echo "<p>Num args: ".$num_args.", Iterations: ".$num_it."</p>";
    var_dump($match);
    return $match;
}
```

Basically the original only saved the one after the found query and stored the 2D array, not the single array making $match a 3D array. Thanks Madara Uchiha for posting